# OS Freya only boots in recovery mode and doesnt hibernate

Tags: system-installation, grub, power

I installed Freya as a dual-boot to Windows. First its not working anyway so I searched the posts and get Grub repaired by purging and fixing it with Boot Repair. That let me boot into Freya some time, but now after updating Freya it will only boot into Freya in recovery mode from grub menu. Same problem is when I told Freya to hibernate it doesnt wake up, shows a blank screen as when I try to boot normal from grub. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Boot using the recovery option in your grub.
Then open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:`

It should now look like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Save it with Ctrl+o then exit with Ctrl+x

Then update your grub using
`sudo update-grub`

Now you'll be able to boot without having to select the recovery option.