# New install of eOS only boots when holding escape

Tags: release-juno, boot

Just installed eOS as the only operating system on a desktop PC via usb-stick. No warnings or anything during installation. But now I have this issue:

When I turn on the PC nothing happens - no signal is sent to the monitor.

However, if I boot while holding escape, it boots into eOS, seemingly with everything working normally. From there I can restart the PC without any issue. However, shutting down, it won't start again unless I hold down the escape.

The desktop has an AMD graphics card.  I have tried running boot repair, which didn't change anything. Also tried this answer, which also didn't work: [OS Freya only boots in recovery mode and doesnt hibernate](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/os-freya-only-boots-in-recovery-mode-and-doesnt-hibernate).

What could be the cause?